# automatically convert GMT time

Tags: javascript

when I print the Date() it brings me the schedule of my machine, but I have a website that is accessed by different parts of the world and I need to show on the site the schedule of only a certain Country "BRAZIL" GMT 0300

Can someone help me ?

how to automatically convert the time showing in the application, regardless of where the user is accessing.

Comment: Use https://momentjs.com/ then you can do something like `moment.utc(utcTime).local().format()`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn OP does not want `local`, he specifically wants brasilian time.

Comment: @Bergi that doesn't change the fact that he could use that library wit the timezone piece. https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize javascript date to a particular timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-javascript-date-to-a-particular-timezone) and/or [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](//stackoverflow.com/q/10087819)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) `toLocaleString()` and specify a timezone like this:

```js
console.log(
  new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Sao_Paulo"})
);
// 5/19/2018, 1:04:43 PM = Time in Brazil
```

Here is a [list of timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) you can use.